# Composer - O que é e pra que serve?

Tags: json, composer

Já vi várias vezes em projetos o arquivo `composer.json`!

Gostaria de saber o que é e para que é usado?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

O [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/) é um gerenciador de dependências para PHP. Ele está para o PHP assim como o `npm` está para o `NodeJS`, ou o `Bower` está para desenvolvimento frontend, ou o `pip` está para o Python...

Ao utilizar o Composer você pode definir as bibliotecas que seu código precisa, através do arquivo `composer.json`. Executando o comando `composer install`, a ferramenta vai baixar todas as dependências para você. Quando suas dependências são atualizadas, você pode pedir que o Composer baixe as atualizações através do `composer update`.

Você pode procurar todas as bibliotecas disponíveis no site [Packagist](https://packagist.org/).

Comment: Ótima resposta, adicionaria dois que não tem haver com programação mas se assemelha, o apt-get e o yum, me corrija se estiver falando besteira :)

Comment: Eu quis manter os exemplos mais na área da programação, mas você está certo, o princípio é o mesmo. A diferença, é que no caso dos teus exemplos, as dependências gerenciadas são no sistema operacional.